# Combine RxJava Observables, SharedPreferences and MVP

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, observable, rx-java2, mvp

How to use sharedPreferences inside observable, as I know take value outside observable is a bad practise.

I have something like this:

```
class City {
    private String tempCelsius;
    private String tempKelvin;
    // other fields

    public getTempCelsius() {
        return tempCelsius;
    }

    public getTempKelvin() {
        return tempKelvin;
    }
}
```

In Presenter I have:

```
    public Single<City> getData() {
        return dataManager.loadCitiesFromDb().
            map(city -> dataManager.makeApiCall(city)
                //getting data, error handling
            )
            .subscribe(city -> view.showCityData(city));
    }
```

By the way my DataManager contains instance of PreferenceHelper.

How can I `showCityData` with temperature based on value from SharedPreferences.

If `Kelvin` use City's method `getTempKelvin()`, else if `Celsius` use City's method `getTempCelsius()`.

From Api I received both, but need to show only once according to saved preferences.

Comment: There are a bunch of Rx+SharedPreferences libraries out there. You then only have to use the usual combinators to get its value at the right time.

Comment: What is the return of `dataManager.loadCitiesFromDb()`? This code looks weird to me, since the getData() is returning a `Single`